# while (cin >> str) Um codigo equivalente em Python

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, c++, while

Preciso ler vários itens sem uma quantidade fixa, em c++ basta fazer while (cin >> str) qual seria um código equivalente em python? tem uma resposta em inglês a está mesma pergunta aqui no stack, porém a resposta está incorreta.

um exemplo em c++:

```
int main() {

string str;
while (cin >> str) {
    cout<<str;
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Axei a pergunta vaga, poderia colocar um exemplo em c++, para que seja feita a analogia com python,

Comment: amigo editei a pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Em Python, a entrada padrão é visível como um arquivo de texto aberto, no objeto `sys.stdin`

Se o arquivo foi redirecionado a partir de outro, o final de arquivo vai ser detectado no `sys.stdin` - sem o redirecionamento, como acotneceria no exemplo de C++, o programa fica pra sempre esperando novas linhas.

Assim, um método comum de arquivos, como o `readlines()` pode ler automaticamnte todas as linhas da entrada padrão. O que ele não faz é converter o conteúdo lido para algum tipo - Python, com toda a expressividade que tem, não tem muitas "mágicas" na sintaxe  - você pode usar uma list comprehension ou a  função `map` para converter todas as linhas lidas para inteiros.

Por exemplo:

```
import sys

dados = map(int, sys.stdin)
```

Pronto - apenas isso - o `map` pede um objeto iterável no segundo argumento - um arquivo de texto, ao ser iterado, emite (yields) uma linha de cada vez. Essa linha é passada para o chamável `int`, que despreza caracteres de white-space - incluindo o newline que vem no vinal da linha. Em resumo: `dados` se torna um objeto  gerador que pode ser usado em um `for`, ou pode ser transformado numa lista com `dados = list(dados)` .

A sintaxe com list comprehension é:

```
import sys

dados = [int(linha) for linha in sys.stdin]
```

Comment: poderia adaptar para String por favor? estou trabalhando com elas.

Comment: Para string você não precisa transformar o valor  - é só fazer  `dados=list(sys.stdin)`, ou `dados = sys.stdin.readlines()` . Só se quiser remover os caractéres de final de linha - `\n`, aí precisa ser `dados = [linha.strip() for linha in sys.stdin()]`